# Sample repository class

Tags: c#

How can I make it shorter and cleaner?

```
using Queries.Core.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Queries.Persistence.Repositories
{
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public TEntity SingleOrDefault(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return Context.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(predicate);
    }

    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().AddRange(entities);
    }

    public void Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        Context.Set<TEntity>().RemoveRange(entities);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How can you make it shorter or cleaner? Every single method delegates to an equivalent method on IDbSet.

Comment: you are good, no extraneous code, nothing to fix.

Comment: @RobH Thanks for your reply. I feel that  I've repeated Context.Set<TEntity>() in every method, so is there any way to not to repeat it?

Comment: lol, I SUPPOSE you could do:' Context Entity { get { return Context.Set<TEntity>(); } }' and then replace every instance with just Entity.Add, Entity.Remove etc... but that is not really that necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're worried about repeating `Context.Set<TEntity>()` about the place, you can assign a field in your constructor instead:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;
    protected readonly IDbSet<TEntity> Set;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        Set = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public TEntity Get(int id)
    {
        return Set.Find(id);
    }
}
```

I would say that I don't generally like generic repositories but I won't get in to that now. A lot of people use the pattern and I don't know of any canonical 'this is bad' sources so am happy to disagree over it.

One thing you do need to consider though: multiple column primary keys. That's why `Find` takes an array (params). You're making a method that will throw if the object has a multiple column primary key (`Get`).

Comment: isn't generic repository has advantage of code-reuse? Correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: *I don't generally like generic repositories* Yeah... If only the EF team had decided to use the name `DbRepository` instead of `DbSet`...

Comment: Off topic, but I use custom repositories in my mobile application development. I use an IRepository that everything derives from, and implement EF on the server side library, and SQLIte on the mobile platforms. An abstracted repo layer just makes things cleaner when dealing with multiple db's in a single solution.

Comment: @M005 I'm fine with generic repositories when they're internal as they do help code reuse. I don't like them when they're public.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be any shorter. It's basically a thin wrapper around a `DbSet`. But I do have a remark about the design.

IMO you shouldn't return `IEnumerable<TEntity>` from `GetAll` and `Find`, but `IQueryable<TEntity>`. There reason is that by returning `IQueryable` you can compose queries comprising multiple repositories that will result in one expression tree and, hence, one SQL query. (I'm assuming that all repositories in a unit of work will receive the same `DbContext` instance.)

With your current code, if you'd join two repository results, like this ...

```
var result = from order in ordersRepo.Find(anExpression)
             join cst in customerRepo.GetAll() on order.CustomerID equals cts.ID
             select new { ... };
```

... you would pull all `Customer` records from the database before the actual join is made. By returning `IQueryable`, this would turn into a SQL query containing a `JOIN` and (obviously) far less traffic.